# What is the best way to keep track of multiple files (strings) with dynamic properties?

Tags: json, string, vb.net, algorithm

I have a settings file that contains a single string. Only one setting can be set at one time but you can have multiple saved settings. I need to be able to reference the setting by name, category, and subcategory. For example, the category is character and the subcategory is what 2 spells are selected for that character. I want to track them by unique name but also be able to look up a character and spell setting as well.

My current solution is to have a directory with each category and then spell combinations sub folders with the file being stored in the last folder with the title of the setting as the file name. However, my problem is that it's very slow and bulky.

I thought I could store all the information in one file but then I have to search each file when a character is selected. There may not be an additional setting for a particular combination either, which means it just stays whatever it was originally.

In summary, I want to list a string by name or character and each character has a subcategory that has a two string combination. Does anyone have any ideas on the best method to approach this problem?

I also thought about using one file in a Json strong and just deserializing and querying it, but the file could be extremely large. I am working on the program in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can take this down if it's useless. I used one file as a map to the rest of the larger files. The map has the basic metadata as well to prevent me from having to search all the files. I am not sure if it is the best answer but it did work for me. I can take this question down if no one finds this useful.